# Socket.io stream crashes on Safari

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream, socket.io

I have set up [Socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) to handle video uploads from client to server like so:

**Client:**

```
var stream = ss.createStream();
ss(Socket).emit('beginUpload', stream, $scope.video);

var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream($scope.videoFile);
var size = 0;

$scope.uploading = true;

blobStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    size += chunk.length;
    var progress = (size / $scope.videoFile.size * 100).toFixed(2);
    //console.log('progress', progress);
    if (progress != 100) {
        updateProgress(progress);
    }
});

blobStream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('ERROR', err);
});

blobStream.on('end', function() {
    Socket.emit('uploadComplete', $scope.video);
});

blobStream.pipe(stream);
```

**Server**

```
ss(socket).on('beginUpload', function(stream, data) {

    // Save stream to file
    var filename = config.upload.tmpFolder+'/'+data.filename;

    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('crashed at begin upload', err);
    });
});
```

Everything works fine when uploading via Chrome, but when I try Safari it sometimes work and sometimes doesnt. The error that appears on the server is:

```
buffer.js:377
      throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
            ^
TypeError: Unknown encoding: buffer
    at Buffer.write (buffer.js:377:13)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:215:28)
    at IOStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:122:15)
    at push (/home/user/www/node_modules/socket.io-stream/lib/iostream.js:147:20)
    at IOStream._onwrite (/home/user/www/node_modules/socket.io-stream/lib/iostream.js:153:5)
    at Socket._onwrite (/home/user/www/node_modules/socket.io-stream/lib/socket.js:231:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/www/node_modules/socket.io-stream/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Socket.onevent (/home/user/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:327:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/home/user/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:287:12)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!